# What is c printf %f default precision?

Tags: c++, c, printf, precision

I'm curious:

If you do a `printf("%f", number);` what is the precision of the statement? I.e. How many decimal places will show up? Is this compiler dependent?

Comment: This is actually defined by the C standard. I've added a tag.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The ANSI C standard, in section 7.19.6.1, says this about the f format specifier:

> If the precision is missing, 6 digits are given

Answer (score 9):

The book, [C:  A Reference Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013089592X) states that if no precision is specified then the default precision is 6 (i.e. 6 digits after the decimal point).

One caveat is if the number is inf (i.e. 1.0/0.0) or NaN then C99 specifies that the output should be inf, -inf, infinity, -infinity, or nan etc....

Answer (score 7):

The default precision for `%f` is 6 digits (see ISO C99 specification, 7.19.6.1/7).