# How to create a variable with more decimal digits than float ANSI C

Tags: c, variables, precision, ansi-c

I have been searching the web for a while now... But I can't find a way to ask the program to print a number with more than 6 decimal digits. I need more decimal digits for precision, since the differences I am trying to measure are way smaller than 0.0000004 (Differences of time small functions need to execute). Is there a way to get better precision?

PS: I am a beginner in programming.

Edit: I should have posted it before:

I am using a simple `clock()` arrangement to get my time. In this case:

```
  double t;
  start = clock();
  f();
  t = (double)(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("t = %lf", t);
```

But it always return me 0.000000, since the minimum value I can give t is 0.000001, and the function "f" takes less than that to run.

Comment: For just configuring `printf` output, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35673394/2891664.

Comment: Generally people work around this by running the function(s) under test repeatedly either for some preset number of times (e.g., a million times), or for a preset time (and count how many times the function ran in, for example, one second).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for datatypes with better precision, you may use double and mention how many digits you wanna print.

More details on datatypes - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/

Comment: I have edited the function to include the structure I am using to get the time value. I need to store nanoseconds at least, the the double value t will only let me store a microsecond. I am sorry for not sending the code structure first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can print 10 digits after the floating point:

```
   printf("t = %.10lf", t);
```

Here is how you can print 15 digits after the floating point:

```
   printf("t = %.15lf", t);
```

Comment: By using that, and the clock time, it will only get me the same precision: with the functions that take more than 0.000001 seconds, for example 0.000123, it will print 0.0001230000... With a bunch of zeros. As many as I use with the `.(number)lf` . Is there a way to get better precision on the time measuring? Since it wont register more decimal cases the way I made it (and posted)