# why there is no loss of precision for this floating point number assigned by sqrt()?

Tags: c, precision

I want to understand how C handles the loss of precision for floating point number.

Here's my simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    double a;
    int i;
    i = 7;
    a = sqrt(i);

    printf("i = %d, a = %lf\n", i, a); 
    printf("a * a = %lf\n", a*a);

    a = 2.645751;
    printf("a * a = %lf\n", a*a);

    return(0);
}
```

Following is the result after cc

> i = 7, a = 2.645751
>
> a * a = 7.000000
>
> a * a = 6.999998

If directly assigned a floating number which is 2.645751, the result of a * a looks understandable to me.

But if a is assigned sqrt(7), why there is no loss of precision for the output of a * a?

That is hard for me to understand.

Comment: ...and the results you got were?..........

Comment: How many digits of precision does `double` have? How many are you printing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is c printf %f default precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207762/what-is-c-printf-f-default-precision)

Comment: Why don't you do `printf("i = %d, a = %.10f\n", i, a);` and tell me if `a` still equals `2.645751`?

Comment: You aren't even looking at half of the precision of `a`.  Hint:  `a` is not `2.645751`.  Try comparing them for equality to see for yourself.

Comment: Why the close flags?  His understanding of the situation is wrong but it's a quite reasonable mistake for a learner to make and thus a good question in my book.

Comment: @LorenPechtel With over [3000](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) consider a vote to re-open now that the question is closed.

Answer (score 6):

Your confusion comes from what is actually held in `a` and what is printed as the default precision by `printf`. From `man 3 printf` *"If  the  precision  is missing, it is taken as 6"*. Therefore when you print with `%lf` (which should be simply `%f` as `%f` is already the *format specifier* for `double`) you are only seeing the value of `a` to the default 6-digit precision. (rounded)

`a` does not contain `2.645751` following your call to `a = sqrt(i);` -- that is just the default precision output by your `printf` statement. You can clearly see this just by specifying a longer precision for the output, e.g.

```
printf("i = %d, a = %.10f\n", i, a);
```

Output:

```
i = 7, a = 2.6457513111
```

So you need to keep clear what is contained in the actual `double` is most likely not what you see when you use `printf` with the default *format specifier* and default *precision*. `double` values (the 64-bits) represent a `1-bit` sign bit, an `11-bit` normalized exponent and a `52-bit` mantissa. Not all numbers are capable of being represented exactly (just due to the limitation of bits to represent every possible number).

A good, but arguably rather dry to read, reference that goes into this a bit further is [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Let me know if this helped your understanding, or whether you still have questions. We are happy to help further.

Comment: For general C questions, it is preferable to cite the C standard rather than the POSIX/Unix/other man pages. The citation for the default of 6 digits could be C 2011  7.21.6.1 8.

Comment: That is exactly what I inartfully attempted to explain. Feel free to take creative license with the wording. (the boss arrived and I had to help with groceries)

Comment: @iBug, you know, I'm just a simple man. All I can do is read. `man 3 printf` states `"f, F  The  double  argument  is rounded and converted to decimal notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd"`, so you may be right in your doubt, but all I can do is read.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Fine. I was wrong.

Comment: Happens to me all the time `:)`

Comment: FYI `%.53f` should be sufficient to see the exact value of a `double` at this scale.

Comment: @R To add: `"%.52e"` should be sufficient to see the exact value of a `double` at _any_ scale - if `printf()` is robust.  An easy alternative to see the exact value is to use `"%a"` - of course the significand is hexadecimal then.

Answer (score 0):

Your assigned `a` as double that have very long precision then the precision you assigned as hard coded. Thus, the precision error you got with the hard coded numbers is visible. At the same time, the precision error with `sqrt()` is not that much to visible, though it is not fully displayed with the `printf()`.

Comment: I've edited your answer to use inline code formatting.