# Real value printed with %f is 0.0000, but condition '>0' does not apply (after using $floor in a task)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I **declare** my variable:

```
real meas_diff_div;
```

I have a task, where I **use** this variable:

```
measure_task(meas_diff_div);
```

After that I **filter for an error based on the value** of this `real`:

```
  if(meas_diff_div > 0)`error("error message. %f", meas_diff_div);
```

Sometimes the **error is triggered, even if the printed value is 0.000000**

At the task declaration, the 1st line looks like this:

```
task measure_task(output real output_value);
```

In the task this `real` is 'filled' up with (I use `$floor` in this context to get around the % 'modulo' operator applied to 'real' problemtype):

```
 output_value = realtime_val1 - realtime_val2 * $floor(realtime_val1/realtime_val2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you `$display` the `real` value.

`%f` shows only zeroes because it does not have enough digits of precision to show very small floating point values.  Use `%g` to show the number in scientific format to see it really is non-zero.  Similarly, use `%f` and specify a large enough precision value.

```
module tb;
    real meas_diff_div;
 
initial begin
    meas_diff_div = 0.0000001;
    if (meas_diff_div > 0) $display("%f"   , meas_diff_div);
    if (meas_diff_div > 0) $display("%1.7f", meas_diff_div);
    if (meas_diff_div > 0) $display("%g"   , meas_diff_div);
end
endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
0.000000
0.0000001
1e-07
```

As you can see, when the signal has a small non-zero value, like 0.0000001, the `if` evaluates to true since it is larger than 0.

Although not explicitly stated in the IEEE Std 1800-2017, `%f` seems to behave like `%.6f` (the default number of digits after the decimal point is 6).  Since this syntax was borrowed from `C`, see also: [What is c printf %f default precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207762/what-is-c-printf-f-default-precision)

For your filter you could do something like:

```
if (meas_diff_div > 0.001) `error("error message. %f", meas_diff_div);
```

---

In your code, the problem is not `$floor`.  The difference of 2 `real` values can produce a non-zero value.